# SQL Server WMI provider is not available

Tags: c#, sql-server, wmi

I am trying to build a simple windows application using C# to return all local servers on my machine,
I am using this code to do that

```
var servers = new List<string>();
var serverCollection = new ManagedComputer().ServerInstances.Cast<ServerInstance>().Select(instance => String.IsNullOrEmpty(instance.Name) || instance.Name == defaultMsSqlInstanceName ?
                                        instance.Parent.Name : Path.Combine(instance.Parent.Name, instance.Name))
                                       .ToArray();

foreach (var server in serverCollection.Where(server => !servers.Contains(server)))
{
    servers.Add(server);
}

return servers;
```

But when I run the application, an unhandled exception of type `Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.SmoException` occurred in `Microsoft.SqlServer.SqlWmiManagement.dll` with the message:

> SQL Server WMI provider is not available on local machine.

any help please?

Comment: What version of SQL server are you referring to?